# How to create instance of class purely based on classname string which is dynamic in nature

Tags: java

I do not have the name of the class whose instance i want to create. But i do have the class name String whose instance i am trying to create (i constructed the String, putting some variables together, so basically it is dynamic in nature) . I do however know the base class. How do i create instance of the class in this case ? I am trying the following but it is not working

```
    Class sc = Class.forName("com.blah.SomeClass");

    Object obj = sc.getConstructor().newInstance();

    BaseClass bc = sc.cast(obj);  //SomeClass is extended from BaseClass
```

Compiler is complaining in this case. I expected sc.cast(obj) would give me instance of SomeClass but doesn't seem to be the case. I do not want to do any of the following because i do not know the class name as i mentioned earlier:

```
    BaseClass bc = (SomeClass) obj; 
 
    Or 

    BaseClass bc = SomeClass.class.cast(obj);
```

What can i do ? That brings me to another question. Aren't sc and SomeClass.class supposed to be same ?

Comment: Why don't you just cast to the `BaseClass`?

Comment: If you don't know anything beyond the `BaseClass` anyways, then it wouldn't really be advantageous to have the object cast as a subclass because you won't know what subclass it is.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

Comment: I want to create instance of SomeClass because i want to make use of polymorphism here

Answer (score 1):

```
Class<BaseClass> sc = (Class<BaseClass>) Class.forName("com.blah.SomeClass");

BaseClass obj = sc.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

should be enough.

You don't need to pass by an intermediary variable since a `SomeClass` is a `BaseClass`.